# complex structure in odd-dimensional real vector space

Tags: symplectic-geometry

If V is an odd-dimensional real vector space, then is there a linear map $J: V \to V$ satisfying $J^2=-1$? i.e. is there a complex structure in odd-dimensional real vector space?

Comment: I guess you mean odd-dimensional Real vector space?

Comment: Of course. @user99680

Comment: Yes, sorry to ask, but we get all sorts of questions in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Hint: Take determinants on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

What would the determinant of such a J be?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @naslundx, the content of what I wrote is exactly the same as that provided by the accepted answer (and was posted before it). You will notice that I was neither critiquing not requesting clarification, but asking a question, answering which would have resulted in the OP solving his problem.

Comment: You are correct, I saw your answer in the review queue (someone else flagged it first) and might have misjudged. Either way, I would suggest starting such a question-answer with the common "Hint:"-text.